# How to Fix schema com.canonical.indicator.datetime not installed error?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-unity

I'm trying to get back the clock in the Unity system bar. I installed unity-tweak-tool but when i try to use it I get an error and it ends.

```
$ unity-tweak-tool 
Error: schema com.canonical.indicator.datetime not installed
```

How can I install the missing schema?

I'm using ubuntu 13.10. And I do a bit of cleanup and maybe (probably) my Ubuntu is missing some dependencies.

**UPDATE:** I'm thinking the problems will caused with the uninstall of Evolution packages.

Answer (score 4):

Solved installing `indicator-datetime` package.

This package installed back evolution packages like `evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common evolution-data-server-goa`

The question is, WTF Why the datetime indicator need evolution-server-* dependency. It's just a clock, isn't? Are we crazy?

Comment: some weird stuff going on there really same thing happened today.

Answer (score 0):

For those who still need a solution: the problem occurs if one uninstalls the overlay scrollbars. To solve the problem install the overlay scroll bars again (sudo apt-get install overlay-scrollbar) and disable them via the Unity Tweak Tool itself. (System->Scrolling)